# Read Excel with Macro from Java

Tags: java, excel, vba

I have excel. and I create macro to the excel file to read data from other resources. the macro run every second and update its excel cells.

Now, I want to build java program to read the excel data every seconds to. I have try Apache POI, but after I check the [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html) ti doesn't support reading excel file with macro.

I read from some resources Java Com Bridge (`JCOB`) can be used to read excel with macro. I've try, But the cell value still not updated every times I try my code.

```
import com.jacob.com.*;
import com.jacob.activeX.*;

public class ExcelTest {
 private static ActiveXComponent xl;
 private static Dispatch workbooks = null;
 private static Dispatch workbook = null;
 private static Dispatch sheet = null;
 private static String filename = null;
 private static boolean readonly = false;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String file = "D:\\tutorial\\ApachePoi\\ratesource.xls";
  OpenExcel(file, false); // do not show false to open Excel
  System.out.println(GetValue("B46"));
 }

 private static void OpenExcel(String file, boolean f) {
  try {
   filename = file;
   xl = new ActiveXComponent("Excel.Application");
   xl.setProperty("Visible", new Variant(f));
   workbooks = xl.getProperty("Workbooks").toDispatch();
   workbook = Dispatch.invoke(
     workbooks,
     "Open",
     Dispatch.Method,
     new Object[] { filename, new Variant(false),
       new Variant(readonly) },// whether to open read-only
     new int[1]).toDispatch();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }

 // Read value
 private static String GetValue(String position) {
  if (workbook == null) {
   System.out.println("workbook is null");
  }
  sheet = Dispatch.get(workbook, "ActiveSheet").toDispatch();
  Object cell = Dispatch.invoke(sheet, "Range", Dispatch.Get,
    new Object[]{position}, new int[1]).toDispatch();
  String value = Dispatch.get((Dispatch) cell, "Value").toString();

  return value;
 }
 //1.3638356164383563
 //1.3638356164383563




 private static void SetValue (String position, String type, String value)  
 {  

 }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with an Excel engine capable of doing what you describe.

Have you considered talking to Excel instead and ask it for its values when running your spread-sheet?  I believe you can do so with ODBC.

Another approach might be creating an OpenOffice version of your sheet and talk to OpenOffice instead.

Comment: the current system using excel to read data from other resources. My job is create program to publish excel data to the some website over Internet. 
In the sheet there are 2 table, I think it's not effective using ODBC, because it specific for one table on one sheet.

Comment: If Excel needs to do the work, you need to talk to Excel, not parse Excel data files.

Comment: what do you mean to talk with Excel ? sorry, my English is not good enough.

Comment: @adisembiring, just having a macro in a file does not mean it magically is executed when the file is loaded by a given framework.  You will need to have it executed by Excel, and then connect to Excel with e.g. ODBC to ask it what the values of the cells are.  Then ask a bit later, and ask later, and ask later.

Answer (score 0):

One pitfall is poi don't change the value of the existing excel write to another file and you can see the difference

```
workbook.getSheet().getRow(1).getCell(0).setValue("test");
```

and  write this(changed) workbook to another file

```
public void writeFile(String fileName) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        getWorkbook().write(fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException occurs");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It can't be like that. because the macro changes the excel value. The macro read data from some datasource, and update its cells

Comment: I know it changes it in runtime but you can't see the difference unless you write this workbook to another file. please test it